# How to create thread pool for mass files download and refactor current code?

Tags: java, multithreading, refactoring, wget

As in question. My current code is overkill for OS because it runs every wget process in seperate thread, which is fine, but I have almost 15k files to download, so I want to use a thread pool for this job. Unfortunately I must use wget for download process.

```
    ExecutorService executor = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(5);
  for(String filename: files) {
        try {
            String encodedFilename = URLEncoder.encode(filename, "UTF-8");
            final String cmd = "wget --no-check-certificate -O " + filename +" " + BipDownloader.bipUrl + encodedFilename;

            Runnable run = new Runnable()
            {
                public void run() {
                    try {
                        System.out.println(cmd);
                        Process process = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(cmd);
                    } catch (IOException e) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }  

                }
            };
            executor.submit(run);
        } catch(IOException e) {
            System.err.println(e.getMessage());
        }    
  }
```

**EDIT**

Updated source code to use Thread Pool but my system still is unstable during download.

Comment: Execute `wget` in [GNU Parallel](https://www.gnu.org/software/parallel/).

Comment: You can use Java concurrency API to create threadpools. [http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/)

Comment: @Tichodroma thanks but I am not sure that works in Win7

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming that you do need to use wget, you can use an [ExecutorService](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ExecutorService.html) to handle a threadpool for you:

```
ExecutorService executor = new FixedThreadPool(100); //pool of 100 threads

...

Runnable r = new Runnable() {

    public void run() {
        try {
            System.out.println(cmd);
            Process process = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(cmd);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }  
    }
}

executor.submit(r);
```

- The optimal size of the pool depends on various factors and it is best to test several numbers. Something between 100 and 1000 should be ok.
- If you need to monitor the progress of the executions, you can store the futures returned by `executor.submit`, or you can use a CompletionExecutorService.

**EDIT**

As noted in the comments, `exec` is non blocking so in theory, it is possible that all processes will be started before any of them has finished, even if the size of the pool is limited. To prevent that you should wait until in your `run` method until the process finishes:

```
Process process = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(cmd);
int exitVal = process.waitFor();
```

Comment: Thanks, so FixedThreadPool will care that there are max 100 thread working at the same time and other threads will run after old threads done?

Comment: @drupality yes that's the idea.

Comment: @drupality Your updated question makes my answer irrelevant, which is not very helpful. And I don't know what you mean by *"my system still is unstable during download"*.

Comment: If I launch program I can't use my computer at all, it's too slow.

Comment: @drupality You are launching many threads and processes, which consumes resources. If you want to consume less resources, use less threads. Why do you use wget instead of retrieving the data directly in Java? It would probably be more efficient.

Comment: Yes I know it. I am using wget because some files are downloadable only via wget. (reverse proxy)

Comment: The runnable should probably wait for the executable to finish, or you are still spawning thousands of processes regardless of the size of the thread pool.

Comment: @MichaelKrussel The exeuctor being a fixed thread pool, it won't spawn more threads than the pool size. If additional runnables are submitted they will be queued until a thread becomes available.

Comment: But the tasks being submitted to the thread pool spawn a process then return.  This means that all the tasks can get run before any of the child processes complete.  The call to exec is non blocking.

Comment: @MichaelKrussel That's a good point - I have edited my answer.